# Run a jar file with Class-Path

Tags: java

I am trying to build a java application and use the command `java -jar myapp.jar` to execute it. However, it keeps throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` of an external library `JSONObject`.

After searching the internet, I have added `org.apache.maven.plugins`, `maven-dependency-plugin` and `maven-assembly-plugin` in my `pom.xml`. The target directory do contains `libs` folder which contains all the libraries that the application needed. Also I can find `Class-Path` has been added in `MANIFEST.MF`.

However, when I try to run it by `java -jar myapp.jar`, it still throws `ClassNotFoundException` of the `JSONObject`. I don't know why, please help.

the `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: user
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_80
Class-Path: lib/json-20170516.jar lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar 
 lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar lib/opencsv-3.9.jar lib
 /commons-lang3-3.5.jar lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar lib/commons-lo
 gging-1.2.jar lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
Main-Class: com.myapp.App
```

Comment: Did you copy the `lib` directory into the same location as your `myapp.jar`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, they are in the same location

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found why, the generated location of libraries is `libs` but the one in Class-Path is `lib`!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, that was because the path in Class-Path is `lib` but the library folder is `libs`!!!!

In my pom.xml

```
<!-- Build an executable JAR -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                // error line
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.ics.monitorlogprocessor.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- Copy dependencies to the build directory (used to upload it later) -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
// the error line

          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

as you can see, the config of `maven-jar-plugin` and `maven-dependency-plugin` are miss matched. Please becareful because the above config is copy directly from old questions.